# ComboBox's SelectionChanged inside datagrid not firing mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light, selectionchanged

I am using MvvmLight toolkit for my event interactions, i have tried many solutions available but none worked. The combo box inside my data grid's Selection Changed event is not firing
Here is my xaml:

i used both InvokeCommandAction and EventToCommand:

```
EventToCommand Command="{Binding rlcCbSelectionChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
 InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding rlcCbSelectionChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Please tell me what am i missing??
Selection Changed event successfully fires on data grid with same procedure given above.

Comment: To help debuging : You can add a breakpoint on the binding and check binding value in "Locals" table. You can read this post for more details : http://10rem.net/blog/2011/04/13/silverlight-5-debugging-bindings-with-xaml-breakpoints

Comment: that is great because silverlight 4 did not have that option and unfortunately i am working with SL4 :(

Comment: Did you try to bind to the `SelectedItem` property?

Comment: no, i bind the SelectedValue property

Comment: well, i also tried the <b>SelectedItem</b>, but no effect at all

Answer (score 0):

Well answer is quite simple i was missing an attribute that is optional that is why i leave this one previously but that causes selection change event not to fire. So i add my view model key as a static resource and it worked :)

So my working xaml look like :

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">

                                    <i1:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding  Path=rlcCbSelectionChanged, Source={StaticResource dvm}}"/>

                                </i:EventTrigger>
```